# How to start a Scrapy/Selenium app written in Python using cron

Tags: python, bash, selenium, cron, scrapy

I am trying to start a python script automatically using cron. The problem is that the program uses selenium, so the application I am trying to run has a Graphic interface. I tried different solutions but nothing seems to work. This is what I have inside the crontab:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/raspberry/bin/../file.sh
```

The bash file contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
scrapy crawl mySpider
```

The file.sh works if I start it manually. What could the problem be? Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Hi Giada,
which user is running the process? Could it be that, when you try to run it manually you run it with user X while when you schedule it you run it with Z? Moreover, do you have any log entries in the logging facility the cron daemon is using? (don't know which distro you are using)

Comment: I think the user is the same. I run the process using the user 'raspberry' and the cron line is saved in the cron file of the same user (I use crontab -e to modify the file). How can I check the log entries? Sorry about the silly questions but I am new to this.

Comment: Giada, which distribution and version are you using of Linux?

Comment: I am using ubuntu mate 16.04 on the raspberry pi3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous attempts, I found the solution to my problem. I post it so it may be useful for other people. Instead of using a bash file I wrote the command directly in the crontab:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && cd /home/... && scrapy crawl MySpider
```